# BackupExec first setup - is this all I need?

Tags: installation, iso, backupexec

I have purchased BE 2010, an SQL agent, an Exchange 2010 agent and 12 server agents. Symantec gave me a link to their website, but no matter with which serial number I log in, I get the same download page, for a DVD image (or a set of divided part-files to assemble a DVD image).

Any idea if all I need is on there, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything for BE comes on the one disc. When you're running through the installation, it will ask you to enter your appropriate license keys, and then it will only install/activate the products that you're entitled to.

After BE is installed, it will will then push the agents out using MSI's remote installation abilities to your servers, so there's no need to install the agents manually (and thus no need to download them manually)

So no, you're not missing anything :)